# Al presionar un botón cerrar MdiContainer

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-forms

Buen Día,

Estoy desarrollando un sistema administrador para la empresa con la cual trabajo. Mi sistema esta basado en C# y estoy trabajando con MdiContainer.

Mi aplicacion comienza asi:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El area remarcada representa el area que contiene al Mdi Container.
El presionar el boton "Examen" se despliega el control de usuario que estoy utilizando que es el siguiente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que pretendo hacer es que al momento de presionar el boton de la "x" (cerrar) el cual es boton que yo inserte pueda digamos cerrar el contenedor y quedar igual que la primer imagen que puse, como si se tratara de volver al index.

Saludos, espero haberme explicado. Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Para cerrar un form tienes que llamar al metodo "close" de la forma.

para poder cerrar una forma desde otra tienes que hacer que esta sea publica y accedible desde donde la quieres llamar.

por ejemplo:

si quieres cerrar FormExamen desde mainform entonces formexamen tiene que ser global para MainForm.

```
   FormExamen.Close();
```

si quieres cerrar Form Examen desde otra form que no es mainForm, entonces FormXamen tiene que ser Global y publica desde Formexamen.

```
   MainForm.FormExamen.Close();
```

si las instancias de manera local perderas cualquier clase de acceso a la form desde otros contenedores y tendras que utilizar otros procesos para acceder a ellas, como controls.find() el cual no me parece muy eficiente.

si quieres cerrar la form examen desde la misma forma entonces no necesitas nada de esto, solo dale doble click al boton "x" e invoca

```
   This.Close();
```